# SQL with SUM() convert to LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have this sql and want to convert it to linq. The sql is merging columns in the db by using SUM and i want to do the same in linq:

```
SELECT 
[company]
  ,[employeeid]
  ,[year]
  ,[period]
  ,[project]
  ,[activity]
  ,SUM(hours1) as day1
  ,SUM(hours2) as day2
  ,SUM(hours3) as day3
  ,SUM(hours4) as day4
  ,SUM(hours5) as day5
  ,SUM(hours6) as day6
  ,SUM(hours7) as day7
  ,[projecttype]
  ,[runtableid]  
FROM ExportHoursToERP 
where runtableid = 6090
group by [company], [employeeId],[year],[period],[project],[activity],[projecttype],[runtableid]
```

This is what I have tried without success so far:

```
var DbRows = from r in dal.ExportHoursToERPs
              where r.runtableid.Equals(6090)
              group r by new { r.company, r.employeeid, r.year, r.period, r.project, r.activity, r.projecttype, r.runtableid } into og
              select new
              {
                  company = r.company,
                  Employee = r.employee,
                  Year = r.year,
                  WeekNo = r.period,
                  Project = r.project,
                  Activity = r.activity,
                  day1 = og.Sum(y => y.hours1)
                  day2 = og.Sum(y => y.hours2)
                  day3 = og.Sum(y => y.hours3)
                  day4 = og.Sum(y => y.hours4)
                  day5 = og.Sum(y => y.hours5)
                  day6 = og.Sum(y => y.hours6)
                  day7 = og.Sum(y => y.hours7)
                  ProjectType = r.projecttype,
                  RuntableId = r.runtableid
              };
```

Comment: What was unsuccessful about it? Did you get an error? Wrong results? Something else?

Comment: Do you have an error? the query looks good, i guess. Also, shouldnt this be with quotes -  `r.runtableid.Equals("6090")` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this

```
company = r.company
```

use this:

```
company = og.Key.company
```

That's because you want to access the property that is part of a grouping key. 
Of course you need to apply the same system for all properties that are part of a grouping object